# How to add global variable to vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I'm getting an error if I write

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});
```

Because vscode doesn't know it's available in this particular environment. Where can I set it to be like, `window`, `document` etc...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create file jsconfig.json with the following content

```
{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["chrome"]}}
```

Comment: Source https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition